# replacing the carriage return with white space in java

Tags: java, regex, drools

I am having the below string in a string variable in java.

```
rule "6"
no-loop true
    when
    then
    String prefix = null;
    prefix = "900";
    String style = null;
    style = "490";
    String  grade = null;
    grade = "GL";
    double basePrice = 0.0;
    basePrice = 837.00;
    String ruleName = null;
    ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_006
Rahul Kumar Singh";
    ProductConfigurationCreator.createFact(drools, prefix, style,grade,baseprice,rulename);
end
rule "5"
no-loop true
    when
    then
    String prefix = null;
    prefix = "800";
    String style = null;
    style = "481";
    String  grade = null;
    grade = "FL";
    double basePrice = 0.0;
    basePrice = 882.00;
    String ruleName = null;
    ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_005";
    ProductConfigurationCreator.createFact(drools, prefix, style,grade,baseprice,rulename);
end
```

I need to replace this the carriage return between "THEN" and "END" keyword with white space so that it becomes like below code:

```
rule "6"
no-loop true
    when
    then
    String prefix = null;
    prefix = "900";
    String style = null;
    style = "490";
    String  grade = null;
    grade = "GL";
    double basePrice = 0.0;
    basePrice = 837.00;
    String ruleName = null;
    ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_006 Rahul Kumar Singh";
    ProductConfigurationCreator.createFact(drools, prefix, style,grade,baseprice,rulename);
end

rule "5"
no-loop true
    when
    then
    String prefix = null;
    prefix = "800";
    String style = null;
    style = "481";
    String  grade = null;
    grade = "FL";
    double basePrice = 0.0;
    basePrice = 882.00;
    String ruleName = null;
    ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_005";
    ProductConfigurationCreator.createFact(drools, prefix, style,grade,baseprice,rulename);
end
```

In the above two example of string set, the second is correct format that I need. However, in the first set, I am getting this :

```
ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_006
Rahul Kumar Singh";
```

This perticulerly needs to be like this:

```
ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_006 Rahul Kumar Singh";
```

and I also need to ensure that this doesn't effect any thing else in the string.
Thus I need to replace this "carriage return" with a white space and make in one line. This is my requirment. I tried with replace and replaceAll method of string but not works properly.

Problem:

> I need to look in between string "then" and "end" and in that whenever
>   there is any carriage return in between two double quaotes "" ""; I
>   need to replace this carriage return with white space and make it in
>   one line.

Thanks

EDIT:

DRT:

```
template header
Prefix
Style
Product

package com.xx
import com.xx.drools.ProductConfigurationCreator;

template "ProductSetUp"
rule "Product_@{row.rowNumber}"
no-loop true
    when
    then
      String prefix = null;
      prefix = "@{Prefix}";
      String style = null;
      prefix = "@{Style}";
      String product = null;
      product = "@{Product}";
      ProductConfigurationCreator.createProductFact(drools,prefix,style,product);
end
end template
```

The excel and drt are for only demostration purpose.
In the Image, in Product column, there is "SOFAS \rkumar shorav". Actually this is creating problem. This will generate like below:

```
product = "SOFAS
kumar shorav";
```

I need this like below:

```
product = "SOFAS kumar shorav";
```

Then Excel data :

attached image.[image]

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What about spaces before when, then in the input string?

Comment: How are you doing the replacement? In a text editor? Or reading the file from Java and doing the replacement? Is the original file a valid rule file (or whatever it is)? If it is invalid, then why are you trying to fix it?

Comment: 1) Are you able to extract the section to replace? 2) Are you able to replace carriage returns with whitespaces? 3) Are you able to combine 1 and 2?

Comment: I used replace all and replace method but it is giving me in single line. I want the structure same but only to replace between "then" and "end" word.

Comment: the above code is a string in the same format as it is shown.

Comment: @Kumar Can you please show the code you have written so far so that we know that you have attempted something and are actually stuck somewhere?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the space should be intact ; only I need to replace the content.

Comment: @bot string.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' '); this is replacing all in a single line.

Comment: Have you tried extracting everything between `then` and `end`?

Comment: @Kumar must it always one line between then and end in file?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in Java? How did it happen in the first place? Why can't you simply edit the file? (It hasn't really got anything to do with Drools.)

Comment: From "I need to replace this the carriage return between "THEN" and "END" keyword with white space" is not clear. What if there are more instructions in this section? Should them also be placed in one line? Also in your example you moved indentation to right of all lines below `rule "6"`, which has nothing to do with your question. Was that intentional and you really also want to do this, or was it simple mistake in example?

Comment: @Pshemo I mean to say that I need to look in between string "then" and "end" and in that whenever there is any carriage return in between two double quaotes "" ""; I need to replace this carriage return with white space and make it in one line.

Comment: @Pshemo yes..this will only happen here and in between quotes only.

Comment: @Pshemo and one more thing is that the above string can repeat many time in that file.

Comment: OK, nevermind, I confused `when then` with `then end`.

Comment: @Pshemo did u get any solution for this.

Comment: If I had, I would post it :)

Comment: Is it possible that string will contain `"` literal? I mean is there a way for `ruleName` to contain data representing for instance `hello"world`? Something like `hello\"world`?

Comment: @Pshemo sorry I did not get your question.

Comment: If you replace carriage returns, why do your desired output lines start on a new line? What characters exactly do you want to replace and what do you want to replace them with exactly?

Comment: @Kumar For instance in Java we can create string which will be able to print `"` character if we escape it with ``\``. Like `System.out.println("foo\"bar")`. As you see the middle `"` here is not treated as metacharacter representing end of string but as simple literal which allows us to print it. So is such escape mechanism possible in case of your data?

Comment: @Bohemian I want to replace the new line character only to be replaced with white space so that all the words between "" "" will be in one line.

Comment: @Pshemo no it is not possible.

Comment: @Pshemo Actually this string is generating from drt and converting in to drl string that is compiled by rule engine. However when there is any new line character witing "" it is not able to compile. Thus I need to make it in a single line so that it can be compiled by rule engine.

Comment: Why don't you fix the template??

Comment: @laune is it possible in template?? I am reading the string from excel sheet and in the cell value I have these string.

Comment: Please add the definition of the column(s) and the data entered in the spreadsheet to your question. - Fixing the origin of the problem is better than to patch.

Comment: @laune I updated as you said. Thanks

Comment: Apparently you can't force the person(s) responsible for data entry to avoid line breaks. So we need to inspect the expansion process where the template is filled with values from the spreadsheet. Can you show how this is done? Typically, it is a spreadsheet reader obtaining fields of row and inserting them in a call to the template expander. It should not be difficult to tweak this step to replace newlines.

Comment: Ah, and please tell me the Drools version you are using - I think I can provide a fix without requiring to post-process the generated DRL.

Comment: @laune Drools 6.X version I am using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76226/discussion-between-kumar-and-laune).

Comment: @laune Could you tell me the way, How it is possible. I tried something but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say that there is a bug in org.drools.template.parser.StringCell, method

```
public void addValue(Map<String, Object> vars) {
    vars.put(column.getName(), value);
}
```

Here, the value is added to the Map as a String but this does not take into account that string values are usually expanded into string literals. Therefore, an embedded newline should be converted to the escape sequence `\n`. You might try this patch:

```
public void addValue(Map<String, Object> vars) {
    String h = value.replaceAll( "\n", "\\\\n" );
    vars.put(column.getName(), h);
}
```

Take the source file, put it into a suitable subdirectory, compile it to a class file and make sure that the root directory precedes `drools-templates-6.2.0.Final-sources.jar` in the class path. You should then see

```
ruleName = "SIVM_BASE_PRICE_006\nRahul Kumar Singh";
```

in the generated DRL file. Obviously, this is not a space, *but it is what is written in the spreadsheet cell!*

I suggest (urgently) that you *do not* follow this approach. The reason is simply this that strings are *not always* expanded between quotes, and then the replacement would result almost certainly in invalid code. There is simply no remedy as the template compiler is "dumb" and does not really "know" what it is expanding.

If a String in a spreadsheet contains a line break, template expansion **must** render this faithfully, and break the line just there. If this produces invalid (Java) code: why was the line break entered in the first place? There is absolutely no reason *not* to have a space in that cell if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex I would probably write my own formatter which will

- check if cursor is inside quote
- replace each `\r` with space
- replace each `\n` with space, unless it was placed right after `\r` which means that space was already placed for that `\r`
- write rest of characters without change.

Only possible problem is that this formatter will not care about where string is placed so if you want to format some specific part of the string you will need to provide only that part.

Code implementing such formatter can look like:

```
public static String format(String text){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean insideQuote = false;
    char previous = '\0';//to track `\r\n`

    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {

        if (insideQuote && 
                 (ch == '\r' || 
                  ch == '\n' && previous != '\r') ) {
            sb.append(" ");//replace `\r` or `\n` with space
        }else {
            if (ch == '"') {
                insideQuote = !insideQuote;
            }
            sb.append(ch); //write other characters without change
        }
        previous = ch;
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

helper utility method

```
public static String format(File file, String encoding) throws IOException {
    String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), encoding);
    return format(text);
}
```

Usage:

```
String formatted = format(new File("input.txt"), "utf-8");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: @Kumar That is strange. I just tested it with your example and it seems to be working fine: http://ideone.com/wg3Pb7

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?m)^([^\"]*(\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)\r?\n\\s*", "$1 ");
```

This replaces lines with an unpaired quotes to one with the line ending replaced.

```
^.... means starting at the line begin
[^\"] means not quote
\r?\n catches both CR+LF (Windows) as LF (Rest) line endings

not-quotes,
    repetition of " not-quotes ",
    not quotes, quote, not-quotes, newline
```

Mind this does not cover backslash+quote, escapes them-selves.

Comment: Added multi-line (and whitespace on next line).

Comment: Did you test it (because it still doesn't seem to change anything)?

Comment: @Pshemo you are right; I did not test it as the pattern seemed so regular. Apology.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "multi line" flag:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+", "");
```

The multi-line flag `(?m)` makes `^` and `$` match start/end of each line (rather than start/end of input). `\s+` means "one or more whitespace characters".

Comment: I'd really like to see lines where the start of a line has been removed while keeping the preceding end of a line. ;-) You should realize that `^` and `$` are anchors (or zero-width assertions) and cannot themselves be replaced. This `replaceAll` removes initial white space in each line (but this isn't OP's problem).